# Addition with One input

Tags: python, input, output, addition, codio

I am using codio and ran into a challenge that doesn't make sense to me. 
It says "Your code should expect one input. All you need to do is add 12 to it and output the result".

I am new to Python and was wondering if someone could explain what this means. I can't seem to find any information anywhere else.

Comment: Try to edit your question, make the title more specific, so more people can help you.

Comment: You’re goin to have to share more info than this.

Answer (score 0):

This is asking you to make a function which adds 12 to any number you input.

This could be done as follows:

```
def add_12(num):
    return num+12
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a task definition. You have to write a function which accepts one input parameter, add `12` to it, and return back to caller.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is as below:

print(N+12)

Comment: This question is already answered, if you think there is something to add to this question,  you should put at least a different solution from what is answered here.